# What are the patological mechanisms in asthma?

Tags: asthma

What is the up to date art of knowledge about precise molecular mechanisms in asthma condition ? Were there disvovery of new mechamisms in the last decade or so ? Is it known why does the bronchi tissu alteration cannot be reversed ?
I guess the subject is vast, so you can refer me to books or articles for details.

Comment: Would you understand the answer? I.e. Do you have a background in medical sciences (genetics/molecular biology/anatomy&physiology, etc.)

Comment: Yes I do have such a background.

Comment: Then you should be able to do google scholar searches to find the latest on thoughts and research on asthma.